# Keep list elements in the same line when resizing. CSS liquid layout

Tags: css, overflow, menuitem, drop-down-menu, liquid-layout

I have this menu I found how to made on a tutorial but I have just one trouble. When I resize the page all the layout changes to fit into the new window size but the menu seems to make new lines when the text doesn't fit on the screen. I want that all the menu remains in one line even if the size of the window is too small to show it all. I have tried lots of hacks I've found here but no one seems to work for me. This is the CSS I'm using.

```
#navcontainer {
margin: auto;
width: 95%;
}
#menu
{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
list-style: none;
background: #C2D1DA;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #C2D1DA),color-stop(1, #DDE7ED));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
background: linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
}
#menu li
{
float: left;
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
position: relative;
line-height: 0;
}
#menu a
{
float: left;
height: 13px;
padding: 0 25px;
color: #1A6B91;
text-transform: uppercase;
font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 0px 1px #004063;
}
#menu li:hover > a
{
color: #333;
}
*html #menu li a:hover /* IE6 */
{
color: #333;
}
#menu li:hover > ul
{
display: block;
}
/*SUB MENU*/
#menu ul
{
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 23px;
left: 0;
z-index: 99999;
background: #DDE7ED;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #C2D1DA),color-stop(1, #DDE7ED));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
background: linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu ul ul
{
top: 0;
left: 190px;
}
#menu ul li
{
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #0A486C, 0 2px 0 #1A6891;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #0A486C, 0 2px 0 #1A6891;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #0A486C, 0 2px 0 #1A6891;*/
}
#menu ul li:last-child
{
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
#menu ul a
{
padding: 10px;
height: 10px;
width: 170px;
height: auto;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
float: none;
text-transform: none;
}
*html #menu ul a /* IE6 */
{
height: 10px;
width: 170px;
}
*:first-child+html #menu ul a /* IE7 */
{
height: 10px;
width: 170px;
}
#menu ul a:hover
{
background: #0186ba;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
background: linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
}
#menu ul li:first-child a
{
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
#menu ul li:first-child a:after
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: -8px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid #DDE7ED;
}
#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after
{
left: -8px;
top: 12px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 0; 
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
border-top: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 8px solid #DDE7ED;/*cambiar por gradiente*/
}
#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after
{
border-bottom-color: #04acec;
}
#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after
{
border-right-color: #04acec; /*cambiar por gradiente*/
border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}
#menu ul li:last-child a
{
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after
{
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
font-size: 0;
content: " ";
clear: both;
height: 0;
}
```

And the HTML code for the menu structure is here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7)
{
    $('li').has('ul').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').hide();
    })
}
});
</script>
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#" onclick="inicio();">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ISO 9001</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nueva A.C. o A.P.</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tabla A.C. y A.P.</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="muestras();">Muestras</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="muestras();">Solicitud de Muestra</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="muestrasPendientes();">Muestras Pendientes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Muestras Terminadas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Garant&iacute;as</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cat&aacute;logo de Productos</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="proyectos();">Proyectos</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="proyectos();">Nuevo Proyecto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="proyectosVista();">Proyectos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nueva Actividad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Actividades Proyectos</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="tickets();">Tickets</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="tickets();">Nuevo Ticket</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="ticketsAbiertos();">Tickets Abiertos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="ticketsTerminados();">Tickets Terminados</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="ticketsPorTerminar();">Tickets por Terminar</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="iCalendar();">iCalendar</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="mkt();">MKT</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="publicidad();">Enviar Boletin</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Juntas</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Nuevo Compromiso</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Compromisos Abiertos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Compromisos Terminados</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Todos los Compromisos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nueva Minuta</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Minutas Anteriores</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendario de Eventos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Recordar Compromisos</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="https://www.estatec.com/webmail" target="_blank">Mail</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
* html #menu{
zoom: 1;
} /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #menu{
zoom: 1;
} /* IE7 */
```

This is the menu as I need it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXLSw.png

This is the problem I got
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B01H9.png

I don't care if the menu shows complete or not but I need it on the same line.
I hope you can help me

Comment: do you need the menu to stretch?

Comment: yes, the menu has to change only it's width and if some elements don't fit then hide them. The optimal solution for me is that when the mouse is over the right corner the content starts scrolling left to be displayed but I think that's too hard to achieve. For now I just want to hide the objects that don't fit. I don't know if I'm being specific enough.

Comment: try "overflow-x:hidden;" on #menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3aSTE/

Set a hard height to the `#menu` and `overflow-y:hidden`

Comment: whoops, that removes the hover states!

Comment: Also here's a neat example of a responsive drop-down http://csscience.com/dropdown-accordion/

Comment: lol, I have just noticed about the hover stuff, you're right it's gone, any idea ):

Answer (score 2):

This is most simple possible answer !

Just add below two properties to your #menu css file,

```
 text-align: left;
    width: 1010px;
```

Hope it will work!

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #C2D1DA;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #C2D1DA),color-stop(1, #DDE7ED));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
    background: linear-gradient(#DDE7ED, #C2D1DA);
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    min-width: 952px;
}
```

Use the `min-width` attribute in the CSS.