# Align <li> elements but hide overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align a bunch of avatars next to each other and not go to the line to look like something like this:

[image]

So I followed some fellow questions in Stackoverflow:

- [How to keep <li> elements on single line in fixed width <ul>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378800/how-to-keep-li-elements-on-single-line-in-fixed-width-ul)
- [Keep list elements in the same line when resizing. CSS liquid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437366/keep-list-elements-in-the-same-line-when-resizing-css-liquid-layout)

I changed my `<li>` elements from `display: inline-block` to the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` but now I can't hide the overflow whatsoever.

As you can see in the picture, avatars overflow on the right after the cog icon... I did `overflow-x: hidden` on the `<ul>` and even the parent `<div>` but no solution.

Unfortunately, I **can't** set a hard `height` and do `overflow: hidden` because the avatars have Twitter Bootstrap drop downs...Any other solutions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: We need to see your markup and CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as the `li` are using `display:inline-block` you simply need to set [**`white-space: nowrap;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on the `ul`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcege2wr/)

You may want to augment this with `width:100%;overflow:hidden;` on the `ul`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcege2wr/1/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I tweaked it to exactly what I needed here: http://jsfiddle.net/wcege2wr/2/